# Callback function is undefined in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Parent component, I have a function which updates the state and as callback executes `searchDocs()`

That function is passed as props in a child component

Problem is cus when that function is called:
 - State is updated 
 - But `searchDocs()` is undefined

Cannot figure out why it is `undefined`?

Parent component - function which is passed:

```
  // Method which is Not triggered and should be
 searchDocs(currentPage = 1) {
    const { selectedFilters, searchTags } = this.state;
    if (!searchTags.length && !Object.keys(selectedFilters).length) {
      return null;
    }
    const data = {
      query: (searchTags || [])
        .filter((item) => !item.id)
        .map((item) => item.name)
        .join(' '),
      concepts: (searchTags || []).filter((item) => !!item.id),
      selectedFilters,
      offset: (currentPage - 1) * PAGE_SIZE,
      pageSize: PAGE_SIZE
    };
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, currentPage });
    return searchNews(data)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ docs: res.hits.hits, total: res.hits.total, isLoading: false });
        return res;
      })
      .then((res) =>
        setLocalSearchResults({
          selectedFilters: this.state.selectedFilters,
          docs: res.hits.hits,
          total: res.hits.total,
          currentPage,
          searchTags
        })
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        errorHandler(err, 'Error searching documents.');
      });
  }


 resetFiltersState = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedFilters: {},
        collectionSaved: false
      },
      () => this.searchDocs()
    );
  };

render() {
  return (
     <CreateCollection resetFiltersState={this.resetFiltersState} />
  )
}
```

Child comoponent:

```
 clearFilters = () => {
    this.closeSaveCollectionPopup();

    this.props.resetFiltersState();  // ==> This is a function which is passed from parent
    this.resetCreateCollectionState();
  };


// Here is where the event is triggered:

 <button className="button" onClick={this.clearFilters}>
   <span className="spacing-outher-right-1">{t('clearFilters')}</span>
     <i className="material-icons md-29">highlight_off</i>
 </button>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your parent component?

Comment: You code should works, the error probably come from a missing part of your class, can you share more code ?

Comment: where is the code for `searchDocs()`?

Comment: `searchDocs()` is in parent component. Actually I am not getting the error `undefined`. In Debugger, I saw that function is undefined and that is reason is why is not called.

Comment: I updated the post with `searchDocsI()` function

Comment: All works fine without errors, problem is cus `searchDocs()` is not triggered

Comment: change searchDocs() to arrow function and try

Comment: Tried and still is not called